# Rank nullity theorem -bijection

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$ be a linear transformation. Which of the following statement implies that $T$ is bijective?
>
> **a)** $\operatorname{Null}(T)=n$
>
> **b)** $\operatorname{Rank}(T)=\operatorname{Null}(T)=n$
>
> **c)** $\operatorname{Rank}(T)+\operatorname{Null}(T)=n$
>
> **d)** $\operatorname{Rank}(T)-\operatorname{Null}(T)=n$

I think that since $T$ is one one n onto... Nullity will be zero... So option **a)** and **b)** are incorrect..

And **c)** and **d)** will be correct.. But the answer is option **d)**. I am not able to understand why option **c)** is incorrect.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct, and why?

Comment: Since T is one one n onto... Nullity will be zero... So option a) and b)  are incorrect..  And c and d will be correct..  But ans is option d..I am not able to understand by option c is incorrect.

Comment: C does not imply that T is bijective. It is true for any general T.

Comment: There is an error in the question, because both (b) and (d) are correct. $T$ is bijective if and only if it is surjective, which is true when its rank is $n$. See Solomonoff's answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(d)$
\begin{align}
R(T)+N(T)=n\tag1\\
R(T)-N(T)=n\tag2
\end{align}
We know $(1)$ holds anyway due to rank-nullity theorem. Thus solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $R(T)=n$ and $N(T)=0$ which implies $T$ is a bijection.

$(c)$ is an incorrect choice. Consider $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(x_1,x_2)=(0,x_1).$ $R(T)+N(T)=n$ will anyway hold. But this $T$ is not a bijection.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to option (d), option (b) is correct. If $n = 0$ then the consequence, $T$ is bijective, is true. On the other hand if $n \ne 0$ then the premise, that the rank equals the nullity, is false. Either way the implication is true.

Answer (score 4):

The question isn't asking you which of the options will be the case if $T$ is a bijection, it's asking which of those prove that $T$ is a bijection. Your reasoning for the first two being incorrect is valid. $c$ certainly doesn't imply that $T$ is a bijection, since it is just the statement of the rank-nullity theorem (for maps from a finite dimensional vector space to itself), which holds for non-invertible transformations. $d$ does imply that $T$ is a bijection, since if the nullity were greater than zero then the rank would be greater than $n$, which is impossible; thus, $T$ is injective, and therefore surjective.

Comment: Your first sentence is a very good insight.  Reading the original question and questioner's comments, it's clear they are assuming $T$ is a bijection and trying to prove a)–d).  That's the opposite of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Option **c)** is incorrect because the null map is not bijective, but assertion **c)** holds for that map.

Answer (score 2):

The statement in part (c) is **always** true; this is the rank-nullity theorem!